# Bash script with non-blocking read

Tags: bash, scripting, nonblocking

I want to send some data to a root process with a named pipe. Here is the script and it works great:

```
#!/bin/sh
pipe=/tmp/ntp

if [[ ! -p $pipe ]]; then
    mknod -m 666 $pipe p
fi

while true
do
    if read line <$pipe; then
         /root/netman/extra/bin/ntpclient -s -h $line > $pipe 2>&1
    fi
done
```

I actually have several script like this one. I would like to enclose all of them in a single script. The problem is that execution blocks on the first "read" and I cannot execute multiple "reads" in a single process. Isn't there anything I can do? Is it possible to have a "non-blocking" bash read?

Comment: Why do you want to combine separate operations into a single script?  If they each work correctly standalone, leave them standalone.  It's much easier than trying to bend the shell into doing non-blocking reads.  Processes are cheap.  Simple processes are also more secure than complex ones, and root processes need to be secure.

Comment: I would agree with you, but each process eats 628K of RAM (it is a copy of the bash) and I am in an embedded environment. I would prefer to save as much memory as possible.

Comment: If it is that much of a problem, write the code in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the reading cycle into background (add & after done)?

Comment: Great! I've halved memory consumption!

Comment: @michelemarcon: are you sure you're saving memory?  When I tested it, adding `&` forced the while loop to execute in a subshell = another process = more memory used.

Comment: Tested with ps, each script eats 628K. With '&', each process eats 240K. And BTW, since every 'while' is on background, the "mother" script exited and freed its memory

Comment: @GordonDavisson subshells instances of bash can utilize the COW semantics of fork() on modern UNIX systems, while separately fork-exec-ed bash instances cannot.

Answer (score 22):

Bash's read embedded command has a -t parameter to set a timeout:

```
-t timeout
    Cause read to time out and return failure if a complete line of input is not
    read within timeout seconds. This option has no effect if read is not reading
    input from the terminal or a pipe.
```

This should help you solve this issue.

Edit:

There are some restrictions for this solution to work as the man page indicates: *This option has no effect if read is not reading input from the terminal or a pipe.*

So if I create a pipe in /tmp:

```
mknod /tmp/pipe p
```

Reading directly from the pipe is not working:

```
$ read -t 1 </tmp/pipe  ; echo $?
```

Hangs forever.

```
$ cat /tmp/pipe | ( read -t 1 ; echo $? )
1
```

It is working but cat is not exiting.

A solution is to assign the pipe to a file descriptor:

```
$ exec 7<>/tmp/pipe
```

And then read from this file descriptor either using redirection:

```
$ read -t 1 <&7  ; echo $?
1
```

Or the `-u` option of `read`:

```
$ read -t 1 -u 7  ; echo $?
1
```

Comment: The *this option has no effect if read is not reading input from the terminal or a pipe.* has some implication. I'm editing the answer to include working examples

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, but maybe I'm running a customized bash.

Comment: @michelemarcon `read` with timeout option is in bash. I think you are using `dash`, what shebang you are using? `/bin/sh`?

Comment: @Majid Azimi GNU bash, version 2.05a.0(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnu)

Comment: It is not necessary to use `exec`. The trick rather is, that your suggestion `exec 7<>FILE` opens FILE in read/write mode and thus avoids blocking on a pipe, if there are no writers. But opening the pipe in read-write mode can also be done directly with the read builtin: `read -t 1 <>/tmp/pipe line` will read one line and wait at most one second for that line.

Comment: @KaiPetzke is right. `exec` is not the important part. The read-write redirection is important. `exec` with read-only redirection fails the same way as read with read-only redirection. It's somehow ugly to have to open a write redirection just to get a timeout behavior, but at least it works.

Answer (score -1):

You can use stty to set a timeout.  IIRC its something like

```
stty -F $pipe -icanon time 0
```

Comment: I get Invalid argument. But this is probably because I'm working with busybox [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busybox]

Comment: @michelemarcon I get the same thing, and I'm not currently using busybox.  But when I am, I've found this page to be extremely useful: http://www.busybox.net/BusyBox.html

Comment: I get an invalid argument error too, with Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: stty works on terminals / serial lines / pseudo terminals. It does NOT work on FIFOs and pipes.