# 'read' not timing out when reading from pipe in bash

Tags: bash, timeout

I create a pipe using

```
mkfifo /tmp/foo.pipe
```

Now, I want to try reading from the pipe for a maximum of 2 seconds, so I execute

```
read -t 2 line < /tmp/foo.pipe
```

The timeout does not occur. Read just sits there waiting for input from the pipe.

The manuals say that 'read' is supposed to work with named pipes. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

```
ls -al /tmp/foo.pipe
prw-r----- 1 foo bar 0 Jun 22 19:06 /tmp/foo.pipe
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  If you accepted answers to your questions by clicking the green check mark next to the best answer (if there is one), people would be more likely to give answers to your questions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your shell is blocking on the open() call before invoking the read builtin.

On Linux, you can open the FIFO for both read and write at the same time to prevent blocking on open; this is non-portable, but may do what you want.

```
read -t 2 <>/tmp/foo.pipe
```

Adapted from: [Bash script with non-blocking read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874993/bash-script-with-non-blocking-read/4875924#4875924)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to flush (and discard) the data from the FIFO:

```
dd iflag=nonblock if=/tmp/foo.pipe of=/dev/null &> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Your shell is the one that is holding it up, it is attempting to read from the pipe to feed the data into the read command, and since it is not getting anything it just sits there waiting.

Answer (score -1):

```
TMOUT=2
read line < /tmp/foo.pipe
```

Comment: That just sets the default timeout, it doesn't change the way `read` actually implements the timeout.